# PHP - Find dead code

Tags: php, codeigniter, code-duplication, dead-code

We have a PHP project (CodeIgniter) with a messy code, I used SonarQube to find duplication and coding bugs.

But it doesn't tell you whether the file is used or not, so it takes more time to solve the issue.

I read about [PHP-DCD](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd) but I don't think it's works with CodeIgniter.
Is there another method to find all the dead code in the project?

Comment: Can you please define "dead code"?

Comment: Unused code/files that sit in the project, it should be deleted but I need to identify them first.

Comment: It'll be very difficult to find a tool for PHP that detects dead code where _dead_ is defined as files that aren't being used, especially in a framework like CodeIgniter where namespaces are wacky and hard to resolve in any sane way outside of the context of the framework. Your best bet is to just profile the code and do this manually. It will be painful, but that is the consequence of using a very badly written framework.

Comment: I will mention that the IDE PhpStorm, however, is somewhat good at finding files that aren't used in your project when you try to delete the file from the IDE. It may not work perfectly with CodeIgniter in some oddball cases, but it could. It's been ages since I've touched anything written in CI.